# What java concurrent blocking collection is most performance friendly?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, collections, concurrency

I've read a lot about concurrent queues in Java however I have no clue what to use when the precedence axiom is omitted.

Here is the real-world situation - I implemented my own executor with following properties:

- **unbounded** ("up to infinity" tasks waiting)
- **recursive** (tasks may spawn new tasks into the same task-pool) that's why I can't use Java Executors - waiting for execution at the end causes exception when running task creates new task.
- **thread-safe** (multiple threads may add or retrieve a task)
- **non-blocking** (in terms of adding new task)
- **blocking** (in terms of waiting for execution)

The worker threads are either working on tasks (runnables) or blocked, waiting for a new task to appear in task-pool.

I intend to maximize the performance, so I avoid locks and conditional variables. The real performance, however, isn't good enough (see below)  - using `LinkedBlockingQueue` as task-pool.

I realized that I actually don't care about which task is executed first, hence queue seems to be overkill. I think some kind of set or "bag" would be sufficient and hopefully faster.

**Question:** What collection and/or general approach would you recommend me to use?

My benchmark - I scheduled 1000 tasks, each `Thread.sleep(15)`. I have measured walltime of running 1000 times the task; then walltime of the executor. The speedup was only slightly above a *half of number of threads* (measured on 2,4,6,....,48) threads.

Comment: So you've measured them. Can you provide this data in a tabular form?

Comment: @christopher sure, please take a look http://pastebin.com/uUMd5iFY The first column is the number of threads, the second one number of tasks (i.g. how many times `Thread.sleep(15)` was called) and, finally, the third one the speedup. As you can see, even on small number of cores (e.g. 8), there's something to improve. I believe replacing queue with other structure could help.

Comment: My second question is, if you have performed these metrics, why can't you infer from this data, which is the most performance friendly?

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep` for profiling anything is bad idea. Use some computation insted.

Comment: @petrbel properies you have mentioned are easy to achieve with standard implementation. You basicly reinvented the wheel. Executors are recursive, thread safe and unbound. To wait for execution to end, keep track of `Future` objects and dont rely on `awaitTermination`

Comment: @Antoniossss Doesn't it also requires some kind of concurrent collection? Could that, even theoretically, help me? I'll definitely try it out ASAP, though. Anyway, why is threadsleeping bad idea? I got my inspiration from this ( https://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/research/computing/performance-characterisation-and-benchmarking/epcc-openmp-micro-benchmark-suite ) microbenchmarks...

Comment: Have you considered using [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)? The use of work stealing queues avoids contention by decentralized control and is better optimized for recursive computations.

Comment: @Antoniossss Anyway, how would you write `addTask` method? The only solution I'm able to come with is this which doesn't work (see comments) http://pastebin.com/Lyxcz99L

Comment: In your `addTask`, increment an unbounded semaphore (or phaser) and have the task decrement on completion. Then wait until the semaphore reaches zero.

Comment: I would add everu task to one future list and wait till all futures are done.

Comment: @BenManes isn't it a great performance killer? I'll try it out, but I'm afraid it's not gonna help much

Comment: @Antoniossss it does not work, does it? Creating a future and adding to a list isn't atomic...

Comment: it doesn't have to and yes it works.

Comment: Anyway, that is only one solution. Here you have another one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html

Comment: @petrbel what gave you the idea that ForkJoinPool was a "performance killer"?  (It was built by possibly the most ridiculously performance-oriented Java developer alive...)